# Why would some features still show Overridden after a revert all --force?

Tags: drush, features

Why would some features still show as "Overridden" even after running a full features revert with the force switch? Below are the commands I am running, for the sake of clarity.

```
drush fr-all --force -y
drush fl
```

Comment: There is a whole thread over on d.o with lots of information about this. http://drupal.org/node/744450 There are quite a lot of reasons why it would. It's quite an open ended question.

Answer (score 16):

A feature or features may not revert for the following reasons as cited by some developers in the [issue queue #744450](http://drupal.org/node/744450):

- If your feature includes a view views cache could cause it to remain changed; especially, the migrate module ([#1](http://drupal.org/node/744450#comment-2739586))
- Other features can cause your feature to be overridden ([#10](http://drupal.org/node/744450#comment-3381532))
- Adding a line in your info file ([#24](http://drupal.org/node/744450#comment-3529452))
- There are hooks overriding or altering your view ([#36](http://drupal.org/node/744450#comment-3852002))
- A view won't revert. So revert the view using the UI ([#62](http://drupal.org/node/744450#comment-4987864))
- When Views UI is disabled, it may cause your view to be overriden ([#64](http://drupal.org/node/744450#comment-4994282))
- A feature is missing an include file ([#82](http://drupal.org/node/744450#comment-6593650))

Answer (score 7):

One way of that happening, that I've tried myself, is to have two seperatere features define content types that use the same CCK field. Doing that it's possible to have different settings for the same field for. That way one them will always be overridden.

Answer (score 2):

There is [more documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/986932) related (https://www.drupal.org/node/986932), including a description of a *silver bullet* solution (Disable and re-enable. be careful and test first).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a known issue, http://drupal.org/node/860974

I am battling that one myself.

It does depend on what you are trying to override.  The output of drush features-diff could be helpful for others to give you a more precise reason.

Answer (score 1):

This may seem stupid, but make sure you have all the files for the feature. One of my files didn't make it to git so it kept showing overridden.